# ViewBag update does not update the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following ViewBag:

```
       ViewBag.AuthObject
```

I'm refering this ViewBag in on of the drop-down s follows:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AuthId, ViewBag.ViewBag  != null ? 
   (SelectList)ViewBag.AuthObject: Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
   "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Also, this is ViewBag is changing during the selection of another drop-down above the above one.
It seems that the dropdown for AuthId does not populate even after the ViewBag changes.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the main problem here. Is it that the ViewBag is changing when another dropdown is selected? Or is it that it is not populating? Where/how are you setting the ViewBag? Why would it be changing when another ViewBag is present; do you have JavaScript targeting your dropdowns or something targeting your ViewBags?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your referencing a different ViewBag than ViewBag.AuthObject, unless you're setting them equal at some point.

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.AuthId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AuthObject, "-- Please select --", new {@class = "form-control})
```